# bisogenet failed to start in cytoscape 3.9.1

Tags: startup, cytoscape

I am trying to use the app Biogenet 3.0 on Cytoscape 3.9.1, but after installation the Status on the app says failed to start. my interenet connection and everything is working. I have unistalled and installed it again and that didn't work.

Have anyone found the same problem and do you know how to fix it? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, Biogenet depends on a package that's no longer available.  The authors might have a workaround.